# MLT Framework. How to add different effects to different clips?

Tags: mlt

How to add different filter for each clips and make fade transition between them?

```
melt "11.MOV" -filter greyscale "12.MOV"  -mix 14 -mixer luma  -filter frei0r.sharpness 0=1
```

that one adds both filters to both clips...

Answer (score 4):

```
melt \
    "11.MOV" \
        -attach-clip greyscale \
    "12.MOV" \
        -attach-clip frei0r.sharpness 0=1 \
    -mix 14 -mixer luma
```

**-filter** adds the effect to the entire track.

**-attach-clip** adds the effect to just ...*drumroll*... the clip!

See `melt -h` for more info.